# Python/Django newbie attempting to combine two lists to a dictionary

Tags: python, django, list, dictionary, django-forms

I am *completely* new to python and django, so forgive me if this seems like a dumb question. I have a feeling I don't really understand what I am dealing with even though I know what I want my result to look like.

I need to have a Dictionary that has two sets of things, and for simplicity I am just going to say that my keys below correspond to an already working query - these are field names. All I want to happen is pre-populate a Django ModelForm with the data that ends up in the list called *values*
 below. The data fetch for values works perfectly. The only reason I want a dictionary is because that is what the Django ModelForm wants passed to it in order to have my initial data for the user to change or accept. I believe I am getting tripped up because this is the first time I have ever dealt with dictionaries, especially in python under django.  I've researched using the dict zip technique and it runs without error, but everything ends up being bound to the key I've called name which is of course coming from the field name of a database table.

If I put a import pdb ; pdb.set_trace right before my return statement and ask the debugger what data looks like here is what I get:

```
{'name': ['IB Report', 'IB Daily Report', 'Add description']}
```

Can someone set me on the right path?

```
def mysql_ser_reports_mgmt(id):

    keys = ['name','subject','description']
    values = []

    for report in Report.objects.filter(id=id):
       values.append([str(report.name), str(report.subject), str(report.description)])

    data = dict(zip(keys,values))

    return data
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django already has a filter method which does what you are looking for. [Look into `values()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values)

So, you would do:

```
return Report.objects.filter(id=id).values('name', 'subject', 'description')
```

The output would be something like this:

```
[{'name': 'name', 'subject': '<Subject>', 'description': '<Description>'},
 {'name': 'name2', 'subject': '<Subject2>', 'description': '<Description2>'},
]
```

Comment: That suggestion is definitely a help, however I am trying to work through a Value Error: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 3; 2 is required -- on that return statement you posted above..

Comment: do you get that when you use `values` ? Replace all of your code with just this 1 line. It does the same thing

Comment: That is fantastic! I have done exactly the above. The return statement is the only thing left. I am now blowing up somewhere else...

Comment: ValueError at /ser_reports_mgmt/2
dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 3; 2 is required
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/ser_reports_mgmt/2
Django Version: 1.3.1
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value: 
dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 3; 2 is required
Exception Location: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py in __init__, line 240

Comment: That could be something to do with the forms accepting only 2 arguments instead of 2..

Comment: Trying to figure that one out now - so new to this.. I have three fields, not two on the form - so the message doesn't even appear to make sense to me yet...

Comment: Can you create a new question if you are stuck for too long with the form code? It looks like a separate issue to me.

Comment: Thanks, I sure will - but I want to take a look with the debugger first! Who knows, maybe I'll get a clue and won't have to post!